# how to access form.cleaned_data values in another view?

Tags: python, django, session, django-views, django-templates

urls.py

```
app_name = "spotify"
urlpatterns = [
path("home/" , Search.as_view() , name= "home"),
path("data/" , View.as_view(), name= "view")
]
```

views.py

```
class Search(View):
    
form = SpotifyForm
    template_name = "spotify_calls/homepage.html"
    context = {"form": form}

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request , self.template_name, self.context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args , **kwargs):
        form = self.form(request.POST)
        template_name= "spotify_calls/display.html"
    
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned = form.cleaned_data["form"]
            context = {"data":cleaned}
            return redirect('spotify:view')
            
        else:
            form()

class display(View):
  template_name = "spotify_calls/display.html"
 
   def get(self,request):
        render(request, self.template_name)
```

I wish to pass `context = {"data":cleaned}` into my `class display(View)` so I can use the form data as input to other methods I will define in `class display(View)` but I do not know how to.